# Android how to convert string into datetime format?

Tags: android

I have in String variable this ... "2015-01-12 19:00:00" So I want to convert to DateTime value , I have tried with this....

```
  SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  Date d = dateFormat.parse(fecha);
```

But I can't compile, I have gotten this message ... cannot convert from java.util.Date to java.sql.Date

How fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pattern is actually wrong, try this

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date d = dateFormat.parse(fecha);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have imported `java.sql.Date` instead of `java.util.Date`.